# PHP: How to communicate with mail server thru SMTP?

Tags: php, smtp

How to communicate with mail server thru SMTP using PHP?

Comment: Clarify your question if you think people don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a socket using [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). Write to the socket using [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php). Read from the socket line by line using [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) or byte by byte using [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  NOTE:  when using `fwrite()` to communicate back to the smtp server, you must terminate your command strings with a newline **`"\r\n"`** character for the smtp server to begin executing your command.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this snippet for the `Email()` method of my personal [PHP framework, phunction](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/), maybe it can be of some help. The regex I used is able to validate each individual reply from the SMTP server.

```
if (isset($smtp) === true)
{
    $result = null;
    $stream = stream_socket_client($smtp);

    if (is_resource($stream) === true)
    {
        $data = array('HELO ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $result .= substr(ltrim(fread($stream, 8192)), 0, 3);

        if (preg_match('~^220~', $result) > 0)
        {
            $auth = array_slice(func_get_args(), 8, 2);

            if (count($auth) == 2)
            {
                $data = array_merge($data, array('AUTH LOGIN'), array_map('base64_encode', $auth));
            }

            $data[] = sprintf('MAIL FROM: <%s>', implode('', array_slice($from, 0, 1)));

            foreach (array_merge(array_values($to), array_values($cc), array_values($bcc)) as $value)
            {
                $data[] = sprintf('RCPT TO: <%s>', $value);
            }

            $data[] = 'DATA';
            $data[] = implode("\r\n", array_merge(array_diff_key($header, array('Bcc' => true)), array(''), $content, array('.')));
            $data[] = 'QUIT';

            while (preg_match('~^220(?>250(?>(?>334){1,2}(?>235)?)?(?>(?>250){1,}(?>354(?>250)?)?)?)?$~', $result) > 0)
            {
                if (fwrite($stream, array_shift($data) . "\r\n") !== false)
                {
                    $result .= substr(ltrim(fread($stream, 8192)), 0, 3);
                }
            }

            if (count($data) > 0)
            {
                if (fwrite($stream, array_pop($data) . "\r\n") !== false)
                {
                    $result .= substr(ltrim(fread($stream, 8192)), 0, 3);
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($stream);
    }

    return (preg_match('~221$~', $result) > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation for mail().

Comment: You didn't understood what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Bronislaw I really think he does, here is another resource http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm  If you dont like the answer, be more elaborate in your question.

Comment: I need to send e.g. RCPT TO comand and get response... I don't want to send a mail.

Comment: @Bronislaw Please add that and more detail to your original post.  Put in the work to make the question as clear as possible so we can give ou a very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

These examples use the Pear Mail Package: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-php-send-email-via-smtp-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `Zend_Mail`  it had every function needed to do with mail

-http://framework.zend.com

-http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html